# Why pthread_create can not obtain parameters correctly

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I am using `pthread_create` in my codes, but the thread can not obtain the parameters, my codes are like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h> 
void *readFifo(void *pFd)
{
    printf("get %d\n", *(int*)pFd);  //0
}

int createThreads(char *pipeName)
{
    int pipeFd = 3;
    printf("begin to pass %d\n", pipeFd);  //3 
    pthread_t tid;
    if(pthread_create(&tid, NULL, readFifo, &pipeFd) < 0)
    {
        printf("create thread failed\n");
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    char *pipeName;
    pipeName = argv[1];

    if(createThreads(pipeName) < 0) {
        printf("init read threads failed\n");
        return -1;
    } 
    while(1){
        sleep(10000);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Why I get 0 not 3 in `readFifo`, the `printf` result is `get 0`, did I do something wrong

Comment: `pipeFd` is local to `createThreads`.  There's no guarantee it will still exist by the time the new thread uses the pointer to it.  In fact, it's very likely it will not.

Comment: Use `pthread_join()` instead that ugly loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the first line inside `readFifo` runs, the main thread could have gotten far. It could have exited `createThreads` and destroyed the variable `pipeFd` because it was a local variable inside that function which was destroyed when the function exits. In fact this is very likely. So when `readFifo` reads that variable (by pointer) it gets something else instead.

Answer (score 0):

I convert the parameter to `long int` then to a pointer like [redis](https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/4c74dd986fb18bfc50636db8e259533891183627/src/networking.c#L4229), so my codes are like this

`pthread_create(&tid, NULL, readFifo, (void*)(long)pipeFd`,

then use `(unsigned long)pFd)` to read it,  it works.

@Miles Budnek and @user253751 are also right, if I put `pthread_create` in `main` function, it also works.

Comment: It works because in this case you are not passing a pointer to a local variable, but the variable value itself, temporarily casted to a pointer.